# Server side JSP code to extract/retrieve JSON object from requst

Tags: android, json, jsp, client-server, httpclient

How to retrieve the JSON object that I send with HTTPClient POST method to my server. I want to retrieve this JSON object on server in my JSP page. I googled a lot but either there were no answers or they were all for PHP.

Here is the code from Github that I am using to send data to my server. Code is for client side only. I tried many different ways to access this JSON object in my JSP page on server side, but failed in all my attempts. Also I am a bit confused with the number of JSON libraries that are available on the google.

```
JSONObject jsonobj= new JSONObject();
try {
    // adding some keys
    jsonobj.put("key", "value");
    jsonobj.put("weburl", "hashincludetechnology.com");

} catch (JSONException ex) {
    // some code here
}
// Now lets begin with the server part
try {
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppostreq = new HttpPost(wurl);
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonobj.toString());
    //se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
    se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
    httppostreq.setEntity(se);
    HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppostreq);
    HttpEntity resultentity = httpresponse.getEntity();
    if(resultentity != null) {
        // do other things 
    }
}catch(Exception){
  // Log Exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm too late, but I just answer for the record., Hoping this helps

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Post request recieved !!!");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
    String jsonParam = "";
    if (br != null) {
        jsonParam = br.readLine();
    }
    System.out.println(jsonParam);
    JSONObject obj;
    try {
        obj = new JSONObject(jsonParam);
        System.out.println(obj.get("username"));
        System.out.println(obj.get("data"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Though already I implemented it without JSON, still thanks alot for taking time to answer my question. This will help other users alot.